# Not able to find *.app in mbrola for FreeTTS in Java

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, freetts

I am using speech synthesis in java. I want to change the accent of the speech. So I found that it has to be done through embedding `MBorla` voices in it. I am unable to figure out on how to embed it. I am using the following tutorial: http://freetts.sourceforge.net/mbrola/README.html

Over there they have said to download the binary, I did so; then I downloaded the us1 rar file  named `us1-980512.zip` and extracted it.

In the tutorial they are using mac machine to do this. But I am using a windows 8 64 bit machine.

Anyways, so they said that there should be a file like `drwxrwxrwx  3 jim staff    102 Mar  5  2001 MbroliX.app` but i cant find any `*.app` anywhere I downloaded. 
I am a newbie and expect a detailed help from you people.

Answer (score 0):

MbroliX.app is only available for Mac OS X.Try to download binary files for [Windows](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html)